# Why does my OpenGL Win32 app depth is limited and how to increase it?

Tags: c, winapi, opengl, depth-buffer

My OpenGL scene 3D becomes all black when it outs of the "3D viewport deepth" but i don't succeded to increase the value of the "camera depth far value"

Here is my whole code if you want to C/C in code blocks

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void EnableOpenGL(HWND hwnd, HDC*, HGLRC*);
void DisableOpenGL(HWND, HDC, HGLRC);

float relx = 0.0f;
float relz = 0.0f;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    HWND hwnd;
    HDC hDC;
    HGLRC hRC;
    MSG msg;
    BOOL bQuit = FALSE;
    float theta = 0.0f;

    /* register window class */
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_OWNDC;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = "GLSample";
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);;


    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
        return 0;

    /* create main window */
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0,
                          "GLSample",
                          "OpenGL Sample",
                          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,
                          1024,
                          768,
                          NULL,
                          NULL,
                          hInstance,
                          NULL);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    /* enable OpenGL for the window */
    EnableOpenGL(hwnd, &hDC, &hRC);

    /* program main loop */
    while (!bQuit)
    {
        /* check for messages */
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            /* handle or dispatch messages */
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            {
                bQuit = TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            /* OpenGL animation code goes here */
            glViewport(0,0,1280,720);
            glDepthRange(0,100000);
            glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
            glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            glPushMatrix();
            glRotatef(relx, 0,1,0);
            glRotatef(-10, 1,0,0);
            glTranslatef(-0.5, -0.75f, relz);

            glBegin(GL_QUADS);

                glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex3f(0,0,0);
                glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex3f(1,0,0);
                glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex3f(1,1,0);
                glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex3f(0,1,0);

            glEnd();

            glBegin(GL_QUADS);

                glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex3f(0,0,1);
                glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex3f(1,0,1);
                glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex3f(1,1,1);
                glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex3f(0,1,1);

            glEnd();

            glBegin(GL_QUADS);

                glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex3f(0,1,0);
                glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex3f(1,1,0);
                glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex3f(1,1,1);
                glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex3f(0,1,1);

            glEnd();

             glBegin(GL_QUADS);

                glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex3f(0,0,0);
                glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex3f(1,0,0);
                glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex3f(1,0,1);
                glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex3f(0,0,1);

            glEnd();

            glBegin(GL_QUADS);

                glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex3f(0,0,0);
                glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex3f(0,1,0);
                glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex3f(0,1,1);
                glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex3f(0,0,1);

            glEnd();

             glBegin(GL_QUADS);

                glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex3f(1,0,0);
                glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex3f(1,1,0);
                glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex3f(1,1,1);
                glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex3f(1,0,1);

            glEnd();

            glPopMatrix();

            SwapBuffers(hDC);

            theta += 1.0f;
            Sleep (1);
        }
    }

    /* shutdown OpenGL */
    DisableOpenGL(hwnd, hDC, hRC);

    /* destroy the window explicitly */
    DestroyWindow(hwnd);

    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            return 0;
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        {
            switch (wParam)
            {
                case VK_ESCAPE:
                    PostQuitMessage(0);
                break;
                case VK_LEFT:
                    relx += 1;
                break;
                case VK_RIGHT:
                    relx -= 1;
                break;
                case VK_UP:
                    relz += 0.1;
                break;
                case VK_DOWN:
                    relz -= 0.1;
                break;
            }
        }
        break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

void EnableOpenGL(HWND hwnd, HDC* hDC, HGLRC* hRC)
{
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;

    int iFormat;

    /* get the device context (DC) */
    *hDC = GetDC(hwnd);

    /* set the pixel format for the DC */
    ZeroMemory(&pfd, sizeof(pfd));

    pfd.nSize = sizeof(pfd);
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |
                  PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 24;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 160000000;
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_DIRECT3D_ACCELERATED;

    iFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(*hDC, &pfd);

    SetPixelFormat(*hDC, iFormat, &pfd);

    /* create and enable the render context (RC) */
    *hRC = wglCreateContext(*hDC);

    wglMakeCurrent(*hDC, *hRC);
}

void DisableOpenGL (HWND hwnd, HDC hDC, HGLRC hRC)
{
    wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
    wglDeleteContext(hRC);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hDC);
}
```

I tried `glDepthRange(0,100000);` but unsuccessfull, my 3D cube became black if too far and I want to increase the value of "too far"

Comment: It has nothing to do with ```C```, and ```C++``` as you tagged, although ```Win32``` API looks entirely like ```C``` style.

Comment: `glDepthRange` specifies how **normalized** depth values after clipping are mapped to the depth buffer. Everything that is not in range [-1, 1] is already removed before this transformation is applied. If you want to specify the world space depth values that are visible, you need to use a projection matrix. The problem is btw totally unrelated to using the WinAPI to create the context; it is a pure OpenGL problem.